# Does order matter for targets in a makefile rule?

Tags: makefile

If I have a makefile rule of the following form:

```
target.1 target.2 target.3 : prereq.1 prereq.2 prereq.3
        ...
```

Does the order of the target files matter?  If so, when and how?

Comment: Written that way, no. The dependencies and action are identical for all 3 targets, so it doesn't matter. If you wrote your targets out in separate lines, then they're processed in the order in which they appear in the file.

Comment: There may be confusion.  If by "processed" you mean the recipes are run, then the targets not processed in the order in which they appear in the file.  They're processed in the order in which they are found as prerequisites for some other target.  If you had an `all: target.2 target.3 target.1` then first `target.2` is built, then `target.3`, then `target.1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is only one place where target order matters: the first explicit target defined in the makefile is the default target, that will be built if you run `make` without any arguments.

So, if the above is the first rule in the makefile then `target.1` would be the default goal and the rest won't be.

Not directly related to your question, but it's not clear you have a full understanding of exactly what that rule does; you may want to read this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61938665/939557

Comment: I've got the bit about parallel vs. grouped rules.  The recipe in the above rule would only produce 1 of the listed targets.  I didn't provide a recipe (which would have made that clear) in the question because I didn't think it was pertinent.

Comment: That's good.  99.9% of the time when I see people use _<manytargets> : <manyprereqs>_ in a makefile in SO, it's because they think it does something different than what it does.